# Can I change default location of .emacs.d folder?

Tags: init-file

Emacs 28.1

By default folder `.emacs.d` location on my home folder. Smt like this:

```
/home/alex/.emacs.d/
```

But I need to change to another location to e.g:

```
/home/alexeij/dev/.emacs.d/
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Use a symlink, or redefine HOME?

Comment: Check https://github.com/plexus/chemacs

Comment: I'm betting this is a duplicate question...

Answer (score 3):

This is documented extensively in [chapter 49.4.4 How Emacs Finds Your Init File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html). Always check the manual first.

Quoting the most relevant paragraphs:

> Emacs looks for your init file using the filenames ~/.emacs.el,
> ~/.emacs, or ~/.emacs.d/init.el in that order; you can choose to use
> any one of these names. (Note that only the locations directly in your
> home directory have a leading dot in the location’s basename.)
>
> Emacs can also look in an XDG-compatible location for init.el, the
> default is the directory ~/.config/emacs. This can be overridden by
> setting XDG_CONFIG_HOME in your environment, its value replaces
> ~/.config in the name of the default XDG init file. However
> ~/.emacs.d, ~/.emacs, and ~/.emacs.el are always preferred if they
> exist, which means that you must delete or rename them in order to use
> the XDG location.

So there you have it; just set `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to `/home/alexeij/dev` whenever you run Emacs.

Comment: Be careful about leaving `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` around: there is a search order and emacs stops when it finds the *first* one in the search list.

Comment: The phrasing of the documentation is confusing. "[C]an also" implies that the behavior is not the default but it is.

Comment: No, it’s not confusing. If `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` has no value then Emacs doesn’t use it. Your distribution may automatically give it a value, but that too is something you control.